# Как правильно оформить код с двумя пакетами?

Tags: java, ооп

Требуется решить пример `x + y` в другом файле, а после получить значение `z` и вывести его в первом файле, как это можно реализовать, в мыслях такой код.

`MainActivity.java`:

```
package com.my.supp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.my.supp.second;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public void onClick(){
        TextView textview;

        float x = 15;
        float y = 22;

        second second = new second(x, y)

        textview.setText("" + second.math(z));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

`Second.java`:

```
package com.my.supp;

public class second {

    public void math(float args[]){
        float x = MainActivity.x
        float y = MainActivity.y
        float z = x + y;
        return z;
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы представленный код компилировать пробовали?

Comment: нет, пока не компилировал, т.к. решить основную проблему самостоятельно не могу, а именно вытащить значения из одного пакета в другой и обратно, поэтому отправил имеющийся на данный момент

Comment: У вас _не определены_ поля `x, y` в классе `MainActivity`, на которые вы пытаетесь сослаться в классе `second`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создайте второй класс в таком виде:

```java
public class Calculator {
    public float sum(float x, float y) {
        return x + y;
    }
}
```

Теперь, использовать в `MainActivity` его можно следующим образом:

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Calculator calculator = new Calculator();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
        textView.setText("Result: " + calculator.sum(15, 22));
    }
}
```